# Instance member cannot be used on instance of nested type?

Tags: ios, swift, enums, uiviewcontroller

I have the following code below and Xcode keeps giving me an error I do not understand how to solve.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var manager: Manager?

    enum Link {
        case faq
        case tos

        var url: String {
            switch self {
            case .faq:
                return "www.google.com"
            case .tos:
                return manager!.isFreeUser ? "www.google.com" : "www.duckduckgo.com"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The error is:

> Instance member ‘manager’ of type 'ViewController' cannot be used on instance of nested type 'ViewController.Link'

Answer (score 13):

I'd go with putting the computed variable to the class level:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    private var manager: Manager?

    enum Link {
        case faq
        case tos
    }
    var link: Link = .tos

    var url: String {
        switch link {
        case .faq:
            return "www.google.com"
        case .tos:
            return manager!.isFreeUser ? "www.google.com" : "www.duckduckgo.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

You are trying to access a property of the `ViewController` class inside a seperate code environment, being the enum `Link`.

An easy solution would be to pass your value, in this case `manager` as a parameter to the enum like so:

```
enum Link {
    case faq
    case tos(Manager)

    var url: String {
        switch self {
        case .faq:
            return "www.google.com"
        case .tos(let manager):
            return manager.isFreeUser ? "www.google.com" : "www.duckduckgo.com"
        }
    }
}
```

And whenever you access your enum value, pass in your `manager` property.

```
print(Link.tos(self.manager!).url
```